# How do I get an artifact with a classifier when using Gradle version catalogs in a Kotlin project?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-dependencies

I'm trying to set up a Kotlin project which wants some runtime-only dependencies, but those dependencies come from a classifier.

I'm using a `libs.versions.toml` catalog file to store all the versions, but Gradle decided that the catalog file can't store classifier info, so now I'm trying to find a way to specify it that doesn't use the catalog.

```kotlin
kotlin {
    // ...
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                // ...
                implementation(libs.lwjgl)
                implementation(libs.lwjgl.openvr)

                runtimeOnly(libs.lwjgl.openvr) // but want classifier = "native-windows"
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}
```

**Tried so far**

1. On [a Gradle ticket](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16665), they say it would be this:

```kotlin
runtimeOnly(libs.lwjgl.openvr) {
    artifact {
        classifier = "native-windows"
    }
}
```

However, this does not work, as there is no overload for `runtimeOnly` which takes both an `Any` and a configuration action. If I provide it as a string, it works, but then I'm not using the version catalog anymore.

2. The similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71485996/gradle-version-catalog-classifier) would have me use this:

```kotlin
implementation(variantOf(libs.lwjgl.openvr) {
    classifier("native-windows")
})
```

However, this doesn't appear to be valid either - No `variantOf` function exists, I can't find anywhere to import it from, and nobody thus far has said where they got it from.

3. I then tried the usual hack of breaking out things like `.apply{}`... but it doesn't look like the type of the object I get at any point is the right type to be able to set the classifier.

So I'm out of ideas, short of discarding the catalogs feature in yet another project because it's blocking me doing anything useful.

Versions in play:

- Gradle 7.5.1
- Kotlin Multiplatform Plugin 1.6.10

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches you tried work perfectly fine, ..., **in the top-level `dependencies { ... }` block** for which they exist and where they are used in the examples where you got them from.

Your problem is, that you try to use them in the highly custom Kotlin Gradle Plugin specific `dependencies { ... }` block where those capabilities are missing even in 1.9.10. In the top-level `dependencies { ... }` block you operate on a `DependencyHandler` for which those methods are defined. Where you try to use them, you operate on a `KotlinDependencyHandler` that simply has no direct support for this which you should complain about to JetBrains.

What you can use are the usual work-arounds, which is either using the top-level dependencies block, or at least using the `variantOf` method through it within the Kotlin dependencies block.

Here three ways that all work fine:

```
kotlin {
    jvm()
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by existing {
            dependencies {
                runtimeOnly(dependencies.variantOf(libs.lwjgl) { classifier("native-windows") })
            }
        }
    }
}

val jvmMainRuntimeOnly by configurations
dependencies {
    jvmMainRuntimeOnly(variantOf(libs.lwjgl) { classifier("native-windows") })
    jvmMainRuntimeOnly(libs.lwjgl) { artifact { classifier = "native-windows" } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this while trying to solve the same issue.

```
runtimeOnly(libs.lwjgl.openvr) {
    artifact {
        classifier = "native-windows"
    }
}
```

this worked for me once I upgraded to Gradle 8.

Also works for Kapt, fyi. My specific use is:

```
kapt(libs.querydsl.apt) {
    artifact {
        classifier = "jpa"
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually isn't helpful for the OP and doesn't answer his question, because you use this in the top-level `dependencies` block where it works, not in the Kotlin Gradle Plugin specific highly-custom `dependencies` block where this capability is missing even in 1.9.10. ;-)